# jQuery : put a variable AND a selector inside the $('selector')?

Tags: jquery, selector

could you please tell me if it's possible de use a selector like that :

> $(s_li, '#tools')

s_li is a variable, and '#tools' is the selector, i'd like to bind an event to both of those targets. My exemple doesn't work, do you any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As @Sime (+1) implies, this depends entirely on what `s_li` *is*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If s_li is a selector string:

```
$(s_li + ', #tools')
```

If s_li is a reference to a DOM element:

```
$(s_li).add('#tools')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do $('#selector1, #selector2')...

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ For more detail.