# jQuery: pass parameter to function

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing

I want to pass a parameter into my function.  The parameter will be a variable that representsa CSS class name.  Based upon which checkbox was selected I will set the value of the variable (eg, if CheckBox1 was selected the value of the variable would be the class name '.list1').

The dropdownlist has a large number of options and I want to select a subset of the options based on their 'class' and use those options to populate another list (fl_listEmpty).

Here is my code as far as I've gotten:

```
        function FillDropDownList(parameter) {
            $('.fl_list1 [**put class name parameter here**]).each(function (index) {
                $(".fl_listEmpty").append($('<option> </option>').val(index).html($(this).text()));
            })
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery : put a variable AND a selector inside the $('selector')?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642923/jquery-put-a-variable-and-a-selector-inside-the-selector) ... please use the search before you ask a question. [This was asked like ... a lot of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+variable+selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compose the selector as if it were a string (which it is).

```
    function FillDropDownList(parameter) {
        $('.fl_list1 ' + parameter).each(function (index) {
            $(".fl_listEmpty").append($('<option> </option>').val(index).html($(this).text()));
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your space is intentional between classes, a find would be appropriate. If it is possible that the value may be undefined, you could just make a condition:

```
function FillDropDownList(parameter) {
    var selset = parameter ? $('.fl_list1').find('.' + parameter) : $('.fl_list1');
    selset.each([** your function here **]);
}
```